# Trying to scrape onto next web page

Tags: loops, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, iterator

This is the code that i have so far

```
for page in range(1, 5):
    guitarPage 
   =requests.get('https://www.guitarguitar.co.uk/guitars/electric/page-'.format(page)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(guitarPage, 'lxml')
    # row = soup.find(class_='row products flex-row')
    guitars = soup.find_all(class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3')
```

This is the actual loop to iterate over the products

```
    for guitar in guitars:
        title_text = guitar.h3.text.strip()
        print('Guitar Name: ', title_text)
        price = guitar.find(class_='price bold small').text.strip()
        print('Guitar Price: ', price)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

The code so far only, runs through the same page, without moving on to the next page.
The structure of the URL of the website works around page-2,page-3 ++ and so on.

Comment: Check the way you build your url. Where are `{}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add {} to your link. I have added also time module.

```
      import requests
      from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
      import time

      for page in range(1, 5):
          guitarPage = requests.get('https://www.guitarguitar.co.uk/guitars/electric/page-{}'.format(page)).text
          soup = BeautifulSoup(guitarPage, 'lxml')
          # row = soup.find(class_='row products flex-row')
          guitars = soup.find_all(class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3')
          for guitar in guitars:
              title_text = guitar.h3.text.strip()
              price = guitar.find(class_='price bold small').text.strip()
              print('Guitar Name: ', title_text, 'Guitar Price: ', price)
              time.sleep(0.5)
```